# limma model.matrix design for crossover study

Tags: r, statistics, rna-seq, limma

I'm working with data from a crossover disease study to run limma on. The data would look something like this:

[image]

If I wanted to create a design matrix where I cared about how gene expression changes with condition interacting with time, would it look something like:

model.matrix(~Person + Condition + Time + Condition:Time) or
model.matrix(~Condition*Time)?

Comment: I recommend you ask this question, and other bioinformatics questions, over at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and get the advice of an expert (the consequences of getting this step wrong are worth the effort of asking over there)